# Remove Left and Right margin in order to get a bigger table

Tags: tables, fontsize, paper-size, size, dimensions

I need to enlarge this table until it touches the right and left side of the A4 page. In a nutshell I should remove the margins on the sides. It's my first time using latex and I've tried several attempts, but none of them work. I'm pretty sure I'm setting some package wrong

This is the code.
What should I change?

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % align numbers in columns on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next four instructions
\small      % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column space
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see p. 7 of package's user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} d{2.6} @{}} 

%% headers and footers
\caption{X} \label{tab:x} \\
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

% empty final footer
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
 sex & 0.226^{***} & 0.219^{***} & 0.239^{***} & 0.244^{***} & 0.131^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.142^{***} \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.019) & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) \\ 
\addlinespace
 eta & & -0.009^{***} & -0.005^{***} & -0.004^{***} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{*} \\ 
  & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev2 & & & 0.330^{***} & 0.163^{***} & 0.129^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.129^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev3 & & & 0.717^{***} & 0.459^{***} & 0.420^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.431^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.035) & (0.038) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Middle-class\_worker & & & & 0.219^{***} & 0.189^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.191^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Manager & & & & 0.465^{***} & 0.418^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.410^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.039) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Self-Employed & & & & -0.142^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.190^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.173^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.022) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 acontrib & & & & & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.019^{***} \\ 
          & & & & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 dislav & & & & & & -0.085^{***} & -0.085^{***} & -0.050^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & (0.027) & (0.027) & (0.027) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 occnow & & & & & & &  0.029  &  0.075 \\ 
        & & & & & & & (0.072) & (0.073) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg2 & & & & & & & &  0.147^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.080) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg3 & & & & & & & & -0.005 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg4 & & & & & & & & -0.054 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg5 & & & & & & & & -0.012 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.034) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg6 & & & & & & & & 0.067 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.050) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg7 & & & & & & & & -0.080^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.043) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg8 & & & & & & & &  0.076^{**} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg9 & & & & & & & & -0.018 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.033) \\ 
\addlinespace      
 ireg10 & & & & & & & & -0.071 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.045) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg11 & & & & & & & &  0.050 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.041) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg12 & & & & & & & &  0.012 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.038) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg13 & & & & & & & & -0.099^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.060) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg14 & & & & & & & & -0.217^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.056) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg15 & & & & & & & & -0.091^{**} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg16 & & & & & & & & -0.120^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.040) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg17 & & & & & & & & -0.176^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.054) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg18 & & & & & & & & -0.019 \\
        & & & & & & & & (0.046) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg19 & & & & & & & & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.044) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg20 & & & & & & & & -0.021 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 Constant & 6.860^{***} & 7.530^{***} & 7.133^{***} & 7.034^{***} & 6.273^{***} & 6.324^{***} & 6.266^{***} & 6.171^{***} \\ 
          & (0.015) & (0.089) & (0.082) & (0.078) & (0.082) & (0.083) & (0.166) & (0.170) \\ 
  
\midrule

Observations & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}226} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.081 & 0.270 & 0.358 & 0.455 & 0.457 & 0.457 & 0.476 \\ 
Adjusted $R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.080 & 0.269 & 0.356 & 0.453 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.469 \\ 
Resid.\ Std.\ Error & 0.406 & 0.400 & 0.357 & 0.335 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.305 \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{2227} & \mc{2226} & \mc{2224} & \mc{2218} & \mc{2164} & \mc{2163} & \mc{2162} & \mc{2143} \\
$F$-Statistic 
& \mc{133.081} & \mc{97.706} & \mc{206.134} & \mc{176.461} & \mc{225.471 } & \mc{202.428} & \mc{182.131} & \mc{67.151} \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{1;2227} & \mc{2;2226} & \mc{4;2224} & \mc{7;2218} & \mc{8;2164} & \mc{9;2163} & \mc{10;2162} & \mc{29;2143}  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Note}: $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$} \\  
\end{longtable} 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are already changing `\LTleft` and `\LTright`. Have to tried to use negative values there, e.g., `-1in`, because you've set the margin to `1in`? Or if this should be the whole document, just try using `magin=0in` instead of `margin=1in` and see the `geometry` manual for more information.

Comment: hi @cabohah and thank for the answer! A guy helped me in writing this code, because i'm completely a newbie about it. I've tried to set negative values in `\LTleft` and `\LTright` but nothing seems to happen ( also with huge neegative value). If I set `magin=0in` in `geometry` , only the upper margin is removed, while the left and right ones remain...

Comment: What is wrong your table? Why you use `\-` for coNnecting words in the first column? Using `longtable` you need to compile document more than two times to get final look out.

Comment: hi @Zarko A guy helped me in doing this. I think he uses /- because I was having problem with the original latex output that a statistical tool gave me

Comment: @io_boh I don't know, why nothing happend after your change. As shown in my answer, both suggestions do work.

Comment: It is still unclear, what you like to do with your table. As it is now, looks fine and it nicely fit on page. Why you like that table protrude out of text block, i.e. that it is wider than `\textwidth`.? You should be aware, that such formatting mainly is not acceptable in journals and conferences articles. If the space between columns with numbers is according to your opinion to small, you may consider to make text in the first column narrower by splitting them into two lines, where needed (by use of the ˙\multirow` package). This will work if you can replace `\_` with empty spaces.

Comment: hi @Zarko and thank for the answer. The reason is that I need to put this table in a microsoft word document, which has already the left and right margin... have you any idea about how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained in a comment, you can set `\LTleft` and `\LTright` to `-1in` to extend the `longtable` into the left and right margin, that you've set using `margin=1in` for package `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % align numbers in columns on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next four instructions
\small      % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column space
\setlength\LTleft{-1in}% extend by left margin (see geometry option margin=1in) see p. 7 of package's user guide
\setlength\LTright{-1in}% extend by rightmargin (see geometry option margin=1in)

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} d{2.6} @{}} 

%% headers and footers
\caption{X} \label{tab:x} \\
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

% empty final footer
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
 sex & 0.226^{***} & 0.219^{***} & 0.239^{***} & 0.244^{***} & 0.131^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.142^{***} \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.019) & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) \\ 
\addlinespace
 eta & & -0.009^{***} & -0.005^{***} & -0.004^{***} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{*} \\ 
  & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev2 & & & 0.330^{***} & 0.163^{***} & 0.129^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.129^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev3 & & & 0.717^{***} & 0.459^{***} & 0.420^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.431^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.035) & (0.038) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Middle-class\_worker & & & & 0.219^{***} & 0.189^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.191^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Manager & & & & 0.465^{***} & 0.418^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.410^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.039) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Self-Employed & & & & -0.142^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.190^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.173^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.022) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 acontrib & & & & & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.019^{***} \\ 
          & & & & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 dislav & & & & & & -0.085^{***} & -0.085^{***} & -0.050^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & (0.027) & (0.027) & (0.027) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 occnow & & & & & & &  0.029  &  0.075 \\ 
        & & & & & & & (0.072) & (0.073) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg2 & & & & & & & &  0.147^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.080) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg3 & & & & & & & & -0.005 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg4 & & & & & & & & -0.054 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg5 & & & & & & & & -0.012 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.034) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg6 & & & & & & & & 0.067 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.050) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg7 & & & & & & & & -0.080^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.043) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg8 & & & & & & & &  0.076^{**} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg9 & & & & & & & & -0.018 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.033) \\ 
\addlinespace      
 ireg10 & & & & & & & & -0.071 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.045) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg11 & & & & & & & &  0.050 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.041) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg12 & & & & & & & &  0.012 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.038) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg13 & & & & & & & & -0.099^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.060) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg14 & & & & & & & & -0.217^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.056) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg15 & & & & & & & & -0.091^{**} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg16 & & & & & & & & -0.120^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.040) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg17 & & & & & & & & -0.176^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.054) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg18 & & & & & & & & -0.019 \\
        & & & & & & & & (0.046) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg19 & & & & & & & & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.044) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg20 & & & & & & & & -0.021 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 Constant & 6.860^{***} & 7.530^{***} & 7.133^{***} & 7.034^{***} & 6.273^{***} & 6.324^{***} & 6.266^{***} & 6.171^{***} \\ 
          & (0.015) & (0.089) & (0.082) & (0.078) & (0.082) & (0.083) & (0.166) & (0.170) \\ 
  
\midrule

Observations & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}226} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.081 & 0.270 & 0.358 & 0.455 & 0.457 & 0.457 & 0.476 \\ 
Adjusted $R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.080 & 0.269 & 0.356 & 0.453 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.469 \\ 
Resid.\ Std.\ Error & 0.406 & 0.400 & 0.357 & 0.335 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.305 \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{2227} & \mc{2226} & \mc{2224} & \mc{2218} & \mc{2164} & \mc{2163} & \mc{2162} & \mc{2143} \\
$F$-Statistic 
& \mc{133.081} & \mc{97.706} & \mc{206.134} & \mc{176.461} & \mc{225.471 } & \mc{202.428} & \mc{182.131} & \mc{67.151} \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{1;2227} & \mc{2;2226} & \mc{4;2224} & \mc{7;2218} & \mc{8;2164} & \mc{9;2163} & \mc{10;2162} & \mc{29;2143}  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Note}: $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$} \\  
\end{longtable} 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

But in my opinion, this is too less margin:

[image]

So you should at least change the `longtable` declaration to:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{\hspace{.25em}\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} d{2.6} @{\hspace{.25em}}}
```

(I'll show the result in the next example.)

Alternatively, if you whole document should not have left and right margins, you can set `left` and `right` to 0in with `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=0pt,right=0pt]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % align numbers in columns on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next four instructions
\small      % 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out inter-column space
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}% see p. 7 of package's user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}%

\begin{longtable}{@{\hspace{.25em}\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} d{2.6} @{\hspace{.25em}}} 

%% headers and footers
\caption{X} \label{tab:x} \\
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{$\log(\mathrm{tpens})$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-9} 
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} & \mc{(4)} 
& \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)} & \mc{(7)} & \mc{(8)}\\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

% empty final footer
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
 sex & 0.226^{***} & 0.219^{***} & 0.239^{***} & 0.244^{***} & 0.131^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.132^{***} & 0.142^{***} \\ 
  & (0.020) & (0.019) & (0.017) & (0.017) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) & (0.016) \\ 
\addlinespace
 eta & & -0.009^{***} & -0.005^{***} & -0.004^{***} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{**} & -0.002^{*} \\ 
  & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev2 & & & 0.330^{***} & 0.163^{***} & 0.129^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.127^{***} & 0.129^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 studio\_lev3 & & & 0.717^{***} & 0.459^{***} & 0.420^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.417^{***} & 0.431^{***} \\ 
  & & & (0.035) & (0.038) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Middle-class\_worker & & & & 0.219^{***} & 0.189^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.187^{***} & 0.191^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.023) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) & (0.022) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Manager & & & & 0.465^{***} & 0.418^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.414^{***} & 0.410^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.039) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.037) & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 type\_job\_Self-Employed & & & & -0.142^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.190^{***} & -0.189^{***} & -0.173^{***} \\ 
  & & & & (0.022) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.020) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 acontrib & & & & & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.020^{***} & 0.019^{***} \\ 
          & & & & & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 dislav & & & & & & -0.085^{***} & -0.085^{***} & -0.050^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & (0.027) & (0.027) & (0.027) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 occnow & & & & & & &  0.029  &  0.075 \\ 
        & & & & & & & (0.072) & (0.073) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg2 & & & & & & & &  0.147^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.080) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg3 & & & & & & & & -0.005 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.032) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg4 & & & & & & & & -0.054 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg5 & & & & & & & & -0.012 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.034) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg6 & & & & & & & & 0.067 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.050) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg7 & & & & & & & & -0.080^{*} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.043) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg8 & & & & & & & &  0.076^{**} \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.036) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg9 & & & & & & & & -0.018 \\ 
       & & & & & & & & (0.033) \\ 
\addlinespace      
 ireg10 & & & & & & & & -0.071 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.045) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg11 & & & & & & & &  0.050 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.041) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg12 & & & & & & & &  0.012 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.038) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg13 & & & & & & & & -0.099^{*} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.060) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg14 & & & & & & & & -0.217^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.056) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg15 & & & & & & & & -0.091^{**} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg16 & & & & & & & & -0.120^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.040) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg17 & & & & & & & & -0.176^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.054) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg18 & & & & & & & & -0.019 \\
        & & & & & & & & (0.046) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg19 & & & & & & & & -0.126^{***} \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.044) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 ireg20 & & & & & & & & -0.021 \\ 
        & & & & & & & & (0.039) \\ 
\addlinespace 
 Constant & 6.860^{***} & 7.530^{***} & 7.133^{***} & 7.034^{***} & 6.273^{***} & 6.324^{***} & 6.266^{***} & 6.171^{***} \\ 
          & (0.015) & (0.089) & (0.082) & (0.078) & (0.082) & (0.083) & (0.166) & (0.170) \\ 
  
\midrule

Observations & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}229} & \mc{2{,}226} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} & \mc{2{,}173} \\ 
$R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.081 & 0.270 & 0.358 & 0.455 & 0.457 & 0.457 & 0.476 \\ 
Adjusted $R^{2}$ & 0.056 & 0.080 & 0.269 & 0.356 & 0.453 & 0.455 & 0.455 & 0.469 \\ 
Resid.\ Std.\ Error & 0.406 & 0.400 & 0.357 & 0.335 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.309 & 0.305 \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{2227} & \mc{2226} & \mc{2224} & \mc{2218} & \mc{2164} & \mc{2163} & \mc{2162} & \mc{2143} \\
$F$-Statistic 
& \mc{133.081} & \mc{97.706} & \mc{206.134} & \mc{176.461} & \mc{225.471 } & \mc{202.428} & \mc{182.131} & \mc{67.151} \\ 
\qquad df & \mc{1;2227} & \mc{2;2226} & \mc{4;2224} & \mc{7;2218} & \mc{8;2164} & \mc{9;2163} & \mc{10;2162} & \mc{29;2143}  \\
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{@{}l}{\textit{Note}: $^{*}\ p<0.1$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$; $^{***}\ p<0.01$} \\  
\end{longtable} 
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also remove the top and the bottom margin. Please the the `geometry` manual for more information.

Just my opinion: I always find it difficult to read tables where the columns have been artificially widened. This lacks more orientation in the row and also the cohesion of the values. Because of this, I generally cannot recommend to this.

BTW: Setting `\tabcolsep` to 0pt is usually not the best idea. It can lead to the columns butting up against each other without any spacing.